# How to use Component in page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I'm trying to add a custom component inside several pages.

- I created my pages : `ionic g pages name`
- I created my component : `ionic g component name`

At this point i just  try this :

```
<ion-content>
    <app-menu-button></app-menu-button>
</ion-content>
```

*app-menu-button is component selector*

I get this error : `1. If 'app-menu-button' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.`

i try to add, in my app-module file, this :

```
exports: [
    MenuButtonComponent
  ]
```

But it does not work.

My goal is to display this component in several page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using lazy-loading, you have to import your custom component in the page module. For eg: If you want to use your component `AppMenuButtonComponent` in a page called `ExamplePage`, you have to import it in the page module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ExamplePage } from './example';
import { AppMenuButtonComponent } from '../../components/appmenubutton/appmenubutton';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ExamplePage,
    AppMenuButtonComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ExamplePage),

  ],
  exports: [
    ExamplePage,
  ]
})
export class ExamplePageModule {

}
```

Don't forget to remove your import and declarations from app.module.ts file which was added automatically when you create your custom component.

Answer (score 3):

All components should be declared in the modules like below.

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      MenuButtonComponent
   ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your Component into the declarations array and Entry Components array (if its loading initially) 
`declarations: []` && `entryComponents: []`